# How to change the background color for each group in timeline using timevis in R

Tags: r, shiny, vis.js-timeline

I'm trying to color code the background of a timevis based timeline based on groups divided. I can see that it's possible to color-code the points according to groups, but I need to color-code the background. As you can see in below code, it will change the color of points accordingly.

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(lubridate)

timevisData <- data.frame (
  id          = 1:3,
  content     = c("Klep", "Reinigen", "Zeeppomp"),
  group       = c("Klep", "Reinigen", "Zeeppomp"),
  start       = c("2020-12-10", "2020-12-16", "2020-12-30"),
  end         = NA,
  className   = c("green_style", "green_style", "red_style")
)

groups <- data.frame(
  id = c("Klep", "Reinigen", "Zeeppomp"), 
  content = c("Klep", "Reinigen", "Zeeppomp")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Testing with className",
  h3("Overzicht uitgevoerde en voorgestelde onderhoudsbeurten"),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".red_style   { border-color: red; color: white; background-color: red; }
                     .green_style { border-color: green; color: white; background-color: green; }
                    "))
    ),
  timevisOutput("timeline_aalst")
)

server <- function (input, output, session) {
  output$timeline_aalst <- renderTimevis ({
    timevis (data = timevisData, groups = groups, showZoom = TRUE, options = list(editable = TRUE)) %>%
      setWindow(Sys.Date() %m-% months(1), Sys.Date() %m+% months(1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output will be as follows:

[Achievable Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcM3q.png)

I, however, want the output to be something like

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNDaa.png)

Also, if gridlines could be removed that will be great too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use some advanced  CSS selectors to do the job. So instead of specify the group color inside the dataframe, we do it in the CSS.

Keep rows with the same color together and use `,` to separate the selector.
Number inside `.vis-group:nth-of-type(N)` means the row number. It requires you to know which row a group will go to. If no special case, the first group will go to first row, second group second row,  et al.

```r
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(lubridate)
timevisData <- data.frame (
    id          = 1:3,
    content     = c("Klep", "Reinigen", "Zeeppomp"),
    group       = c("Klep", "Reinigen", "Zeeppomp"),
    start       = c("2020-12-10", "2020-12-16", "2020-12-30"),
    end         = NA
)

groups <- data.frame(
    id = c("Klep", "Reinigen", "Zeeppomp"), 
    content = c("Klep", "Reinigen", "Zeeppomp")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
    title = "Testing with className",
    h3("Overzicht uitgevoerde en voorgestelde onderhoudsbeurten"),
    timevisOutput("timeline_aalst"),
    tags$style(HTML("
        /*green*/
        .vis-foreground .vis-group:nth-of-type(1),
        .vis-foreground .vis-group:nth-of-type(2)
        {border-color: green; color: white; background-color: green;}
        
         /*red*/
        .vis-foreground .vis-group:nth-of-type(3){ border-color: red; color: white; background-color: red; }
    "))
)

server <- function (input, output, session) {
    output$timeline_aalst <- renderTimevis ({
        timevis(data = timevisData, groups = groups, showZoom = TRUE, options = list(editable = TRUE), ) %>%
            setWindow(Sys.Date() %m-% months(1), Sys.Date() %m+% months(1))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So this adds the color to the foreground and you can see it covers the lines connecting the labels to the timeline axis.

[image]

To still display the timeline lines, we can add the color to background, so you need to use following style:

```r
    tags$style(HTML("
        /*green*/
        .vis-background .vis-group:nth-of-type(2),
        .vis-background .vis-group:nth-of-type(3)
        {border-color: green; color: white; background-color: green;}
        
         /*red*/
        .vis-background .vis-group:nth-of-type(4){ border-color: red; color: white; background-color: red; }
    "))
```

Notice the row number for background is row number + 1: `N + 1`, e.g first row is `1 + 1 = 2` instead of 1. This is how it is by the people who develop it, I can't change it.

[image]